# Python: fastest way to check whether two string lists are "similar"

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have two fixed-size string lists, and I would like to check whether the two lists are "similar" as the following example:

```
list1 = ["a", None, "c", None, "e", None]
list2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
similar = True
for i in xrange(6):
    if list1[i] is not None:
        if list1[i] != list2[i]:
            similar = False
            break
```

Is there any faster way to do this ?

**Update:** I just tested some solutions with `zip`. They are not faster since `zip` will consider all of the elements in two lists. Please note that there are many cases where first elements in two lists are different, so the program I provide immediately stops checking remaining elements, leading to a faster solution.

Comment: `all(a is None or a == b for a, b in zip(list1, list2))`, not faster but shorter.

Comment: Probably `all(a==b for a,b in zip(list1, list2) if a and b)` If you specifically have to worry about empty strings giving false positives: `all(a==b for a,b in zip(list1, list2) if a is not None and b is not None)`

Comment: Should `None` in `list2` be treated the same way as it is in `list1`, e.g. is  `['a', None, 'c']` similar to `[None, 'b', None]`?

Comment: @AdamSmith I just tested your solution. It is not faster as `zip` will consider all of the elements in two lists. Please note that there are many cases where first elements in two lists are different, so the program I provide immediately stops checking the remaining ones.

Comment: @NQD That's why we have `itertools.izip`. :-)

Comment: @AshwiniChaudhary: Thanks, but your solution is not really faster.

Comment: @NQD I don't know if you're looking for micro-optimzations or something that's takes **way** less time than an O(N) solution. For micro-optimization you can try something like(considering `None` is the only Falsy item in `list1`): `from itertools import compress, imap; from operator import eq; all(imap(eq, compress(list2, list1), compress(list1, list1)))`. For tiny iterations this may be a little slower compared to a simple loop because of the overhead involved in function calls.

Answer (score 0):

If you're concerned with early exit, you could do:

```
iter1, iter2 = iter(list1), iter(list2)
similar = True
while True:  # or `while similar`
    try:
        a, b = next(iter1), next(iter2)
    except StopIteration:
        break
    if a is not None and b is not None and a != b:
        similar = False
        break
# similar is your result
```

Which is identical to:

```
import itertools

all(a==b for a,b in itertools.izip(list1, list2) if a is not None and b is not None)
```

Which is identical to:

```
import itertools

for a,b in itertools.izip(list1, list2):
    if a is None or b is None:
        continue
    if a != b:
        break
else:
    # similar
```

Comment: It's actually 2-time slower than the code I have. Why I have to create new variables iter1, iters to loop through lists?

Comment: @NQD you don't, but since you're *already* doing the most performant thing, I'm not sure what else you could possibly be asking for. If this is a bottleneck for your program, consider parallelization or simply offloading this to a different language. Python will never be nearly as performant as compiled languages.

Comment: Whether it's slower or not, at least the algorithms presented in this answer are commutative, i.e. `list1` similar `list2` is `True` _and_ `list2` similar `list1` is also True because `None` is treated the same way in both lists. That's more important than speed.

Answer (score 0):

> Is there any faster way to do this ?

Yes, getting rid of the nested `if` will make a small difference:

```
list1 = ["a", None, "c", None, "e", None]
list2 = ["a", "b", "c", "d", "e", "f"]
similar = True
for i in xrange(6):
    if list1[i] is not None and list1[i] != list2[i]:
        similar = False
        break

print(similar)
# True
```

I think that this algorithm is wrong though. If `list1` and `list2` are interchanged:

```
list1, list2 = list2, list1
similar = True
for i in xrange(6):
    if list1[i] is not None and list1[i] != list2[i]:
        similar = False
        break

print(similar)
# False
```

But they are the same two lists and should still be considered similar. IMO this code, which checks for `None` in both lists, is correct:

```
similar = True
for i in xrange(6):
    if ((list1[i] is not None and list2[i] is not None) and
           list1[i] != list2[i]):
        similar = False
        break

print(similar)
# True
```